# Creating a CGEvent tap the right way

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, cgeventtap

I am trying to learn how to create a CGEvent tap using examples on SO and and elsewhere.

I know how to create an event tap using:

```
let eventTap = CGEvent.tapCreate(*/arguments to create the tap*/)
```

After that I run

```
let runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0)
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, .commonModes)
```

Some, but not all examples I've found online also add the following two lines

```
CGEvent.tapEnable(tap: eventTap, enable: true)
CFRunLoopRun()
```

Can someone briefly explain if or when is adding the last two lines are useful/recommended?

Answer (score 3):

The first is easy: [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgevent/1455445-tapenable) say:

> Event taps are normally enabled when created. If an event tap becomes unresponsive, or if a user requests that event taps be disabled, then a kCGEventTapDisabled event is passed to the event tap callback function. Event taps may be re-enabled by calling this function.

The second one is probably for cases where the program doesn't have a [run loop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfrunloop-rht) (on the current thread).  For example, a command-line program which doesn't use [NSApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication) would need to create and run its own run loop.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. If I called CFRunLoopRun() in a program that already had a run loop would it be bad?

Comment: The docs say "Run loops can be run recursively. You can call CFRunLoopRun() from within any run loop callout and create nested run loop activations on the current thread’s call stack."  So whether that's "bad" depends on whether you want nested run loops.

Comment: Yeah I read that later, but it also says: "There is exactly one run loop per thread. You neither create nor destroy a thread’s run loop. " Would this refer to the outer most run loop?
Also, in what scenario would an event tap need a nested run loop?